# Force `tee` to run for every command in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, shell, tee

I would like to have a script wherein all commands are `tee`'d  to a log file.

Right now I am running every command in the script thusly:

```
<command> | tee -a $LOGFILE
```

Is there a way to force every command in a shell script to pipe to `tee`?

I cannot force users to add appropriate `tee`ing when running the ***script***, and want to ensure it logs properly even if the calling user doesn't add a logging call of their own.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do a wrapper inside your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
echo 'hello'
some_more_commands
echo 'goodbye'
} | tee -a /path/to/logfile
```

**Edit:**

Here's another way:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(tee -a /path/to/logfile)
echo 'hello'
some_more_commands
echo 'goodbye'
```

Comment: I like this one - hadn't thought about using brackets

Comment: Use `exec > >(tee -a /path/to/logfile) 2>&1` to also output errors as well to the file in case you're doing a log of EVERYTHING that happens in one file. The `-a` is append, but you can also remove that to start fresh on the file every time.

Answer (score 2):

Why not expose a wrapper that's simply:

```
/path/to/yourOriginalScript.sh | tee -a $LOGFILE
```

Your users should not execute (nor even know about) `yourOriginalScript.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your script doesn't take a `--tee` argument, you can do this (if you do use that argument, just replace `--tee` below with an argument you don't use):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "$1" != --tee ]; then
  $0 --tee "$@" | tee $LOGFILE
  exit $?
else
  shift
fi
# rest of script follows
```

This just has the script re-run itself, using the special argument `--tee` to prevent infinite recursion, piping its output into `tee`.

Comment: Could also use `exec` to not fork extra process:  `if ...; then exec $0 --tee "$@"; else; shift; fi`  (exit will not be needed any more)...

Answer (score 1):

Some approach would be creation of runner script "run_it" that all users invoke their own scripts.

```
run_it my_script
```

All the magic would be done within, e.g. could look like that:

```
LOG_DIR=/var/log/
$@ | tee -a  $LOG_DIR/
```